# non-public selectors "availableDiskSpace"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

It said "The app references non-public selectors in xxx.app/xxx: availableDiskSpace" when I used "Application Loader" to upload my app. But I can not find anything about "availableDiskSpace" in my project. Where and Why?

Comment: Search the project for the string, there's no smoke without fire.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including any third-party frameworks or libraries?  I don't believe the normal search will, for example, look inside static libraries.  But Application Loader will, and this is a common source of private API problems.